# Asynchronous Batch Requests using Facebook Marketing API (JAVA)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-java-api

is there a way to make asynchronous batch requests using [java sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-business-sdk)? The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/asynchronous-batch-requests#example) show some examples using curl only. Does anyone have a java example?

```
    BatchRequest batchRequest = new BatchRequest(context);

    // adding some requests
    request.addToBatch(batchRequest1);
    request.addToBatch(batchRequest2);
    request.addToBatch(batchRequest3);

    List<APIResponse> batchResult = batchRequest.execute(); <-- How to async?
```

Comment: even im trying to do the same. the documents says async batch can only call the following endpoints: `POST /{ad_campaign_id}/copies, POST /{adset_id}/copies, POST /{ad_id}/copies/`. Did you get any leads on this?